# Indentation issues with Eclipse (using Python)

Tags: python, eclipse, tabs

It seems like no matter what settings I use for Python indentation, Eclipse is always causing its own problems.

It keeps missing out entire areas of code, telling me there is an indentation error when there is no white space or incorrect tabs etc and sometimes I have to spend hours just going back over to delete lines and hit return so it is happy. Then sometimes even that doesnt work!

Is anyone else having these issues?

**EDIT:**

Sorry I really should have mentioned. I am using PyDev and have been using tabs all the way through

Comment: Are you using PyDev or another editor?

Comment: Using PyDev I have not had such issues, except when trying to work with source that mixes use of tabs and spaces.  If you have source that sometimes uses tabs, and sometimes uses spaces, you really should take the time to convert the source to use one or the other.

Comment: So did you solve this or not? Any answer useful or solving your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're probably mixing spaces and tabs or you're currently editing a file with a different tab length from your current settings... It'd be nice if you can show a file where you're having those issues and what you were expecting.

Note that if you do have such as issue i.e.: you configured it to have 4 whitespaces and the file you're editing is only using an indentation of 3 whitespaces, it's usually pretty fast and easy to change all that doing a find/replace (Ctrl+F) operation with the whitespaces or a rectangular edit to change multiple lines (Alt+Shift+A).

Another thing to note is that you may end up entering tabs even you use the 'replace tabs with spaces when typing' if you have the option 'assume tab spacing when files contain tabs' in preferences > pydev > editor turned on and the file you're editing has actually some tab.

Answer (score 0):

The general issue was indeed that there were spaces instead of tabs etc.

Although I was aware of this and the issues it could cause and tried to use my settings to work around this, it still caused a lot of problems to no end.

In the end, for me, Eclipse is not sufficient when writing Python, so I shelled out for PyCharm instead, which works far better.